# How to clear highlights in lnav

Tags: command-line, lnav

After `highlight <regex>`. I have no idea how to clear that highlight. With filter we could do a simple `disable-filter <regex>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now a [`clear-highlight`](https://lnav.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands.html#clear-highlight-pattern) command that can be used to clear a previously created highlight.

Comment: Assuming this isn't some sort of impersonator, this is as definitive as it gets. Timothy Stack is the [main author](https://github.com/tstack/lnav/blob/master/AUTHORS) of [lnav](http://lnav.org/)

Answer (score 1):

To clear highlight all you have to do is do an "empty" search.

If to start the highlight I did the following search: `/[DEBUG]`

So to disable it I would just search: `/`

That disables the highlight.